# Expanding tree nodes before AJAX has ended in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, tree, extjs4

I have a search bar docked onto my tree panel. When I write something and press enter an Ajax request fires off and returns the folder ids required to expand the tree up to the point of the folder requested. Inside the success config of the ajax.request I call the expand function of each node via getNodeById using a loop. However after the first expansion ExtJS fires itself an ajax request from the proxy to fetch the folder data (since it hasn't been loaded yet). Since AJAX is asynchronous the loop is faster than the server response and it tries to call the .expand() function of the node before the node itself has been loaded and gives an undefined error. How should I tackle this? I know that generally with AJAX you have to use callback functions for everything you want to run AFTER the request has been processed but I'm not really sure how to do this in this case...

```
Ext.define('treeStore', 
{
    extend : 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    alias: 'widget.treeStore',
    autoLoad : false,
    model : 'treeModel',
    root :  {
        id: 0,
        name : 'Root', 
        expanded : true,
        loaded: true
    },
    proxy :  {
        type : 'ajax', 
        url : 'MyServlet', 
        reader :  {
            type : 'json', 
            root : 'children'
        }
    },
    folderSort: true
});

Ext.define('Ext.tree.Panel',{
.
.
.
//Stuff about the tree panel etc.
dockedItems: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'Search',
        allowBlank: true,
        enableKeys: true,
        listeners: { 
            specialkey: function (txtField, e) { 
                if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER){
                    var searchValue = txtField.getValue();
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: 'MyServlet',
                        params: {
                            caseType: 'search',
                            value: searchValue
                        },
                        success: function(response) { //ATTENTION: When calling the .expand() the AJAX hasn't finished and cannot find the node.
                            response = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                            var panel = txtField.up();
                            response.IDs.forEach(function(entry){
                                panel.getStore().getNodeById(entry.folderId).expand(); <-problem here
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I found out that the expand() function itself has a callback function. I'm trying to find the correct way to take advantage of that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Often when writing my Ext apps, I find that even though things should fire in order, there are times where calling things immediately after an AJAX call is sometimes just too fast.  Maybe the tree nodes have not rendered properly yet, or some other issue.

Try wrapping a delayed task around that code:

```
new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function()
{
    response = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
    var panel = txtField.up();
    response.IDs.forEach(function(entry){
        panel.getStore().getNodeById(entry.folderId).expand(); <-problem here
    });
}, this).delay(100);
```

You'll have to work around those scope issues though. The "this" just before the delay function is your scope.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. I tried the setTimer methods but that isn't what's needed. setTimer waits X amount of time before executing the function inside but the program itself doesn't wait. What I want is for the program to stop moving forward, wait for the AJAX response to load the folder tree data THEN continue on. setTimer doesn't stop the program from running it continues on and just fires the function after X seconds. This doesn't help me since there is nowhere to go if the folder data hasn't loaded yet.